# FirebaseAdmin ListUsersAsync Getting error (The method or operation is not implemented) C#

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase Admin and facing error while retrieving user records. Below is the code which is as per the Firebase Documentation

```
var defaultApp = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(),
            });

            var defaultAuth = FirebaseAdmin.Auth.FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(defaultApp);
            var pagedEnumerable = defaultAuth.ListUsersAsync(null);

            //**GETTING ERROR OVER HERE**
            var responses = pagedEnumerable.AsRawResponses().GetAsyncEnumerator();
```

I am getting error when I use .AsRawResponses(). To me it seems like because the ListUserAsync haven't evaluated and we are using the pagedEnumerable variable.

I am using .net core 2.1. Firebase Admin SDK = 1.9.2

Kindly suggest how I can get the records

Comment: Isn't the message itself clear enough??

Comment: @Tseng, Yes, it's clear but how can I await on it. As await keyword can't be applied over here.

Comment: Reread the message again. It's not about await or not await. Not implemented means **NOT IMPLEMENTED**. You can't use something that's **NOT IMPLEMENTED**. It means there is **no functionality** for your platform and there's too little information provided. Which .NET Core SDK (or maybe even .NET Framework???), which version of the library

Comment: @Tseng Sorry about the missing information, I have edited the question and added the information about platform and libraries.

Comment: There is no async enumerable for .NET Core 2.x, you need 3.x and for the await, well you have to await it if its async, but I think its unrelated. Not implemented means there is no implementation of that method on your target framework. NuGet assemblies can target multiple platforms which not all may implement the same method (due to missing APIs on the target platform)